# I need to pass data from parent to child component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a the below component where I am receiving my data but cannot pass it to the to other component.

```
export default ({ children, query, ...rest }) => {
  // const data = useQuery(query)
  
  return (
    <Query query={query} {...rest}>
      {({ loading, error,data }) => {
        if (loading) return null
        if (error) return <p>Error :()</p>
        {console.log((data.peoples))}
        return (children(data.peoples))
        
    
      }}
    </Query>
  )
}
```

And here I am receiving an error saying that **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'peoples')"** not sure what I am missing

```
export default withData(() => (
  <QueryPage query={query}>
    <Query query={peopleQuery}>
      {({ data }) => {
        {console.log("123456 " + Query.data)}
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <SearchBox />
            <List>
              {data.peoples.map(person => (
                <Link prefetch href={`/person?id=${person.id}`} key={person.id}>
                  <a >
                    <Item content={person.name} />
                  </a>
                </Link>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Fragment>
        )
      }}
    </Query>
  </QueryPage>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

try [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.`

```
data.peoples?.map()
```

Comment: After adding the optional chaining another error pops up

Failed to compile
./pages/people.tsx 23:130
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (23:130)

Comment: can you  create a special codesandbox?

Comment: not too familiar with sandbox but herewith link, I have put the data the I am receiving from the query component into data.  https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-8735vj?file=/data